# Getting Package Details from Composer

Tags: php, composer-php

I've been trying to work my way through the Composer core for most of the day without getting too far. I've been trying to figure out how I can (programmatically, not via the command line), give Composer a package and a version (i.e. `psr/log:1.0.0`), and receive back the package details, similar to [this](https://packagist.org/p/psr/log.json).

If anybody could point me in the right direction it would be much appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try the command: `composer show psr/log`